# Don't want to repeat the number created in a guessing game

Tags: c++

With the help of you guys here, I created a code to create a guessing game.

I feel there is something wrong.
I don't want to repeat the number I craeted in each of the 3 attempts.
Also, in the third attempt, I don't want to see "try again" above"you lose".

Here is the output of my code:

[image]

The expected output is:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int guess, num, attempt = 1;
    srand(time(0));

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        num = 3;
        cout << "Created number is : " << num << endl;

        cout << "Attempt number " << attempt << "..."  << endl;
        cout << "Guess the number: ";
        cin >> guess;

        if (guess == num) {
            cout << "YOU WIN" << ".." << endl;
            return 0;
        }

        else if (guess != num) {
            cout << "Try again" << ".." << endl;
            attempt++;
        }
    }
    cout << "YOU LOSE" << "..!" << endl;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: just change the condition else if (guess != num) in else if (guess != num && attempt < 3) the first cout must be is out of loop for, num is always 3?

Answer (score 1):

Let's get straight to your questions first:

- Write the generated number before starting the loop to avoid that it appears multiple times.
- Check that you are not in the last loop iteration before you output "Try again".

Let me give you some additional hints:

- You might want to get used to `<random>` instead of using the `cstdlib` random facilities.
- You already have a loop where you count the attempts (using variable `i`) so the variable `attempt` is redundant.
- Adding `using namespace std` is considered to be possibly problematic and thus people advise not to use it.
- `std::endl` does two things when applied to `std::cout` which makes `'\n'` in many cases the better option (performance wise):

  1. It adds a newline.
  2. It "flushes" the stream (forces a write to the screen).
- Do not seperate multiple string literals by applying `operator<<` like in `<< "YOU WIN" << ".."` but instead combine the string into `<< "YOU WIN.."`.

Here is the code

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

// Set the maximum number of attempts
constexpr unsigned attempts = 3u;

int main()
{
    // create and seed the random number engine
    std::random_device dev;
    std::mt19937 rng(dev());
    // create a uniform distribution from which you get uniform distributed numbers
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist1_10(1,10);
    // create the initial number
    int num{ dist1_10(rng)}, guess{};
    // Output the created number before starting the loop
    std::cout << "Created number is : " << num << "\n\n";
    
    // Loop for as many times as the game will allow to guess
    for (unsigned i = 1u; i <= attempts; ++i) 
    {
        // Hint to the user which attempt we're at and
        // how many attempts we allow in total
        std::cout 
            << "Attempt: " << i << "/" << attempts << "\n" 
            << "Guess the number: ";
        std::cin >> guess;
        std::cout << '\n';

        if (guess == num) 
        {
            std::cout << guess << " is correct.\n\nYOU WIN!\n";
            return 0;
        }
        std::cout << guess << " is not correct.\n";
        if (i != 3u) std::cout << "Try again.\n";
    }
    std::cout << "\nYOU LOSE!\n";
    return 1;
}
```